# I try to install. package('BMTME')

Tags: r

I try to install. package('BMTME'). I get this message (Warning in install.packages :
package ‘ BMTME’ is not available for this version of R) .I have  already tried to solve this problem in many solutions, but it does not work . please if anyone knows how to solve this problem. thank you `

i tried the way in this link
[How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BMTME/index.html - this package was removed from cran, if you want to download you will have to go to the github page and download

Comment: There hasn't been an update to the github repo in quiet sometime (3 years) I am not sure if the package is maintained anymore - https://github.com/frahik/BMTME